# RIF RIGA -5 GOOGLE SHEET

Tags: google-sheets

RIF RIGA -5 GOOGLE SHEET
.
hello to all, in the formula located in cell e3 of the sheet "Foglio2", there is ref row -5, which I understood what it is for, but in which cases should this -5 be used?
.
is the number of rows that are above the formula ok, but I did not understand when it should be used, I tried to google but I find only rif line
.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rmyCc9b5r0G3yl9CWDH5DhspTVew2opqpk5CmcuvMyU/edit?usp=sharing
thank you very much!

Comment: row(A5:A)  is not a fixed number and in that case we need to subtract 5 from each row number so to have values from 1 to 1000 (or more)

Comment: FYI: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) and [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/399653).

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of the formula in Column E is to sum the values in Column B for each unique value in Column A **once only per unique Column A value**. But how to ensure that the result calculates only once per unique value? This is where the "-5" adjustment is used (more specifically, this adjustment is equal to the row number of the first row of data.

The purpose of the row adjustment is to create an array of numbers that **consistently starts with zero**. When the index value from the `MATCH` formula is compared to the "Row" array value, the index value of any duplicate value in Column A will NOT be greater than or equal to (">=") the Row array and so, the cell in Column E on that row will be be summed.

---

**EXAMPLE**

[image: snapshot]

Comment: thank you very very much!

Comment: If the answer is good, then please consider voting to “accept” it.